# application stopped after cropping image from gallery

Tags: android, image

I'm not able to retrieve image after cropping,here is my code.I choose image from gallery ,crop that image then press save.But after pressing save the application stopped.I'm just looking to crop an image from gallery and then upload it to an ImageView.

```
final int RESULT_GALLERY = 1;
final int CROP_PIC = 2;
protected void setListeners(){
switchCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
         startActivityForResult(galleryIntent , RESULT_GALLERY );
        }
    });
}
```

Here is ActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
{
    if(requestCode==RESULT_GALLERY)
      {
            picUri = data.getData();
            performCrop();
      }
    else if (requestCode==CROP_PIC)
     {
        String imagePath= getRealPathFromURI(picUri);
        android.graphics.Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        ImgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
     }
}
```

this function does the crop operation.

```
private void performCrop() {
// take care of exceptions
try {
// call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
// support it)
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
// indicate image type and Uri
cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
// set crop properties
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
// indicate aspect of desired crop
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
// indicate output X and Y
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
// retrieve data on return
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
// start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
}
// respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     toast.show();
}
```

In logcat

```
07-06 16:17:16.061 18390-18390/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-06 16:17:16.626 18390-18417/jp.co.dorakuken.tcodereaderlibrary D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-06 16:17:16.628 18390-18390/jp.co.dorakuken.tcodereaderlibrary D/Atlas: Validating map...
07-06 16:17:16.660 18390-18417/jp.co.dorakuken.tcodereaderlibrary I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 41a310d, I21d2ab1dda
                                                                            Build Date                       : 08/24/15
                                                                            OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.09
                                                                            Local Branch                     : 
                                                                            Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BF64.1.2.1_rb2.29
                                                                            Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                            Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
07-06 16:17:16.666 18390-18417/jp.co.dorakuken.tcodereaderlibrary I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-06 16:17:16.673 18390-18417/jp.co.dorakuken.tcodereaderlibrary D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
07-06 16:17:16.890 18390-18390/jp.co.dorakuken.tcodereaderlibrary I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@d10a5a5 time:3990330
07-06 16:17:16.890 18390-18390/jp.co.dorakuken.tcodereaderlibrary I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@d10a5a5 time:3990331
07-06 16:17:25.426 18390-18390/jp.co.dorakuken.tcodereaderlibrary I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@d10a5a5 time:3998866
07-06 16:17:27.858 18390-18390/jp.co.dorakuken.tcodereaderlibrary I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@d10a5a5 time:4001298
```

Comment: Can you post the debug logs or crash report when the application stops ?

Comment: @intellignt_idiot In the debug logs,it only show "Frame is not availabe" then application stopped.And also no crash report.

Comment: Can you send me a small test project of your code which i can run directly and debug?

Comment: @Nisarg i can see alittle changes when using picUri= data.getData(); instead of Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); .But another error message (Can't load the image)shows after cropping.

Comment: @Nisarg Here is the code that I changed uri to bitmap..Is something wrong?          InputStream in = null;
 //picUri= data.getData();
 in = getContentResolver().openInputStream( data.getData());
 android.graphics.Bitmap capturedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

Comment: @Nisarg yes,for now ,I can't even crop because of no image data.

Comment: @Nisarg of course it works,but after cropping application stops without error messages.i don't know which code make these error happen because the step over(debugging) can't reach.

Comment: @intellignt_idiot how can i send?(but the code that i uploaded is almost complete for cropping)

Comment: Upload the project on dropbox and share the link here

Comment: @Nisarg  will you do that?please post it.big thanks.

Comment: @Nisarg it did't work.it makes the same error(can't load the image) and can't crop.Sometime can load the image but after crop,stop application as the same before.

Comment: @pes no logcat errors? or update your post

Comment: @pes data.gePath = getRealPathFromURI(picUri); what is data.getPath?

Comment: @Nisarg i changed my code that the way i updated to my post(In ActivityResult)

Comment: @pes what is data.getPath?  i dont get it

Comment: @Nisarg sorry,just my post update mistake.

Comment: @pes can you tell me what is logcat error?

Comment: @Nisarg just updated logcat.

Comment: @pes can you mail me your code if possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(picUri);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);


private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {

        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(contentURI,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        Log.i("getrealpathfrom uri", "" + filePath);
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;

    }
```